# C programming difficulty

Tags: c

Hello everyone i am having a bit of trouble with a project for my class
We just started learning C and I can't get this assignment working, Its a bubble sorter.

I'm unfamiliar with the syntax as we just learned it, but i think the code itself, except the `printValues`, is working... not sure yet how to do that one

It has several errors come up but the first is

```
error: expected expression before 'if'
```

I am also not sure about the second for statement in `sort()

Intended Output:

```
Before:
[7 3 9 4 6 1 2 8 5 ]
[3 7 9 4 6 1 2 8 5 ]
[3 7 4 9 6 1 2 8 5 ]
[3 7 4 6 9 1 2 8 5 ]
[3 7 4 6 1 9 2 8 5 ]
[3 7 4 6 1 2 9 8 5 ]
[3 7 4 6 1 2 8 9 5 ]
[3 7 4 6 1 2 8 5 9 ]
[3 4 7 6 1 2 8 5 9 ]
[3 4 6 7 1 2 8 5 9 ]
[3 4 6 1 7 2 8 5 9 ]
[3 4 6 1 2 7 8 5 9 ]
[3 4 6 1 2 7 5 8 9 ]
[3 4 1 6 2 7 5 8 9 ]
[3 4 1 2 6 7 5 8 9 ]
[3 4 1 2 6 5 7 8 9 ]
[3 1 4 2 6 5 7 8 9 ]
[3 1 2 4 6 5 7 8 9 ]
[3 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
[1 3 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
After:
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
```

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 9

//function prototypes
void printValues(){
    printf("hi");
}//end printValues

void sort(){
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX-1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < MAX -1 - i)
            if (*[i] > *[j + 1])
                swap(*[j]  *[j+1])


}//end sort

void swap(int*h, int*l){
    int temp;
    temp = *l
    *l = *h
    *h = temp
}//end swap

int values[] = {7, 3, 9, 4, 6, 1, 2, 8, 5};

int main(){
  printf("Before: \n");
  printValues();
  sort();
  printf("After: \n");
  printValues();

  return(0);
} // end main
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `)` in your `for` loop in `sort()`.

Comment: Here's a sound idea: check the line that the compiler is complaining about. @kgh is right.

Comment: You don't (usually) want semicolons after `while`s/`for`s. Also, what is this: `*[i]`?

Comment: ye sorry about that )  i must have accidentily deleted it while messing around with the ; 's .  the *[i]  if i'm right is a pointer pointing to the address of i

Comment: I fixed the code... but you really should first go through some tutorial to learn the proper syntax before trying anything else

Comment: As a side note... unless he's teaching himself, what kind of class would try to teach you pointers if you barely grasp the basics of the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.

Some errors in your code:

- using function before declaring it
- mixing `&` and `*`
- missing semicolons
- broken loop syntax (why did you put `;` after it? That would be a do-nothing loop!)
- I also added implementation of the `printValues()` function

Also, `*[i]` doesn't really mean anything. You already have array, so just `values[i]` will do it. You can use ampersand if you want to get it's address (make a pointer).

Also... using a global array for this is not a very good idea. It'd be much better if you passed the array to your sort function as an argument (pointer to it).

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 9

int values[] = {7, 3, 9, 4, 6, 1, 2, 8, 5};

//function prototypes
void printValues(){
    int i;
    printf("[");
    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf(" %d ", values[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}//end printValues

void swap(int* h, int* l){
    int temp;
    temp = *l;
    *l = *h;
    *h = temp;
}//end swap

void sort() {
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX-1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < MAX - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (values[j] > values[j + 1])
                swap(&values[j],  &values[j+1]);
        }
    }
}//end sort

int main(){
    printf("Before: \n");
    printValues();
    sort();
    printf("After: \n");
    printValues();
    return(0);
} // end main
```

Comment: Awesome thank you very much! Again we just started getting into C and the project is due later today so I apologize for that.  What is & though?

Comment: Well I hope you'll read through it and understand what you did wrong, if you just turn this in, it's really good for nothing.

Comment: Of course, I love this class and programming, just don't have very much time before the deadline :), I'm looking it over now to see how it works.